# Float a span over a textarea?

Tags: html, css

html:

```
<div class="no-contact-info">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <span>no contact info</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.no-contact-info {
    width: 400px;
}

.no-contact-info textarea {
    width: 100%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;

    border-right-color: #dbdfe6;
    border-bottom-color: #e3e9ef;
    border-left-color: #e7e8ed;
    border-top-color: #abadb3;    

    z-index: 2;
}

.no-contact-info span {
    display: block;
    background:#FFFFC6 url(/media/icons/error.png) no-repeat 4px center;

    padding: 2px 0 1px 24px;

    color: #333333;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;

    border: 1px solid #abadb3;
    border-top-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    z-index: 1;


    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

view: http://jsfiddle.net/XurSz/

I want to push the "no contact info" span up slightly so that it covers the bottom border of the textarea... but the textarea keeps wanting to go overtop. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `z-index` property only affects elements that have been positioned.  Adding `position:relative;` to the `textarea` and the `span` should do the trick.

Comment: Beautiful! Forgot about that.

Comment: I would add a display inline-block like said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329843/how-to-align-button-to-textarea-corner-and-keep-it-in-same-relative-position-whi